# Change Values of User Model while it has OneToOneField Connection to another model in ModelForms django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

i have problems with Django ModelForms and here is one of them

i wanna have some extra fields for User Model in Django and so made an CustomeUser Model in models.py

#### models.py

```
class CustomeUser(models.Model):
     user = models.OneToOneField(User)
     City = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
     Gender = models.ForeignKey(Gender, null=True, blank=True)
     DateOfBirth = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
     ProfilePicture = models.ImageField(verbose_name="Profile Picture", upload_to=user_directory_path, null=True, blank=True, max_length=255)
     Address = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
     def __str__(self):
         return str(self.user)
```

and now i wanna make EditProfileForm with ModelForm, here is what i did:

#### forms.py

```
class EditProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    firstname = forms.CharField(max_length=35,required=False)
    lastname = forms.CharField(max_length=35, required=False)
    cityid = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=City.objects.values('id').all(), required=False)
    genderid = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Gender.objects.values('id').all(), required=False)
    dateofbirth = forms.DateField(required=False)
    profilepicture = forms.ImageField(required=False, max_length=255)
    address = forms.CharField(max_length=255, required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = CustomeUser
        fields = ['firstname' ,'lastname' ,'cityid' , 'genderid', 'dateofbirth', 'profilepicture', 'address' ]
```

i really have no idea how to do it in the best way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

hooking the `create_user_profile` and `save_user_profile` methods to the User model, whenever a save event occurs. This kind of signal is called `post_save`.

forms.py

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')

class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('bio', 'location', 'birth_date')
```

views.py

```
@login_required
@transaction.atomic
def update_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.profile)
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user_form.save()
            profile_form.save()
            messages.success(request, _('Your profile was successfully updated!'))
            return redirect('settings:profile')
        else:
            messages.error(request, _('Please correct the error below.'))
    else:
        user_form = UserForm(instance=request.user)
        profile_form = ProfileForm(instance=request.user.profile)
    return render(request, 'profiles/profile.html', {
        'user_form': user_form,
        'profile_form': profile_form
    })
```

profile.html

```
<form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ user_form.as_p }}
  {{ profile_form.as_p }}
  <button type="submit">Save changes</button>
</form>
```

you can prefetch related data in a single database query:

```
users = User.objects.all().select_related('profile')
```

*You can change fields and class name instead of using Profile

Comment: you mean that i have to use two forms instead of once?

Comment: Tx Ebrahim
If I add a `Profile` through the admin console : [link](http://localhost:8000/admin/account/profile/add/), it will complain that the user has not bio, location & dob.
Is there an easy way to enforce the 2 ?
Another question is : If I want to have the user that have accounts with a special form (their _Customer_ number for instance `regex='\d{8}'`) and user that have "normal" unconstraint usernames.

Comment: I think you try to access profile for superadmin or for normal user you don't save profile info.

Comment: @Shaonshaonty but the Profile is in my list of console managed classes ... so I should be able to access it from there, no ?