# When develop a Django project, how to design the User model?

Tags: python, django

In Django project, there is a default User model, because in the database, there is auth_user table:

[image]

So, when I create a the User model in models.py, whether I should inherit the django's User or inherit models.Model? Because I should use the permissions in my project.

---

**EDIT**

and, what's the Django's User model? if is the `django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractUser`?

Comment: A good starting point is the documentation on it: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model

Comment: Do you want to add extra field with user model ?

Comment: @Shaonshaonty Yes, I want.

Comment: You can follow this link. [Django Defalut User model modifed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45127085/change-values-of-user-model-while-it-has-onetoonefield-connection-to-another-mod/45128682#45128682) I think it will help.

Comment: @Shaonshaonty And, can I inherit from the Abstract User when I design the User and AdminUser ? which is convenient ? because I will use the Permissions.

Answer (score 0):

How to custom permissions:https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-permissions.  And in terms of editing the default User model, you can either extend the user model or custom the user model, but normally you should extend the user model because you don't need to also custom the authentication system, django already provide a default authentication system associate with the User model. But if the default authentication system or User model doesn't fit your need, you can also make your own User model and authentication system, check this for detail: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model